# returning values greater than the target value

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to change this code.  Instead of counting the number of times that the target value appears, I want to be able to return the number of values in the list that are greater than the target value.

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    counter = 0
    for element in myList:
        if element == target:
            counter = counter + 1
    return counter
```

Do I change the 5 line too?

```
counter > counter + 1
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would think to change line 5 and what you think that would do?

Comment: Also, you should accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark. This will mark the question as complete. Good luck with Python!

Answer (score 4):

The change is fairly trivial:

```
if element > target:  # if the element is greater than the target
```

Don't forget to properly indent the line that follows this.

Note that the most *Pythonic* way to write this function would be to use [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    return sum(1 for element in myList if element > target)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension approach:

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    return len([element for element in myList if element > target])

print countTarget2([1,2,3,4], 2)  # prints 2
```

UPD:

This is actually a short form of:

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    l = []
    for element in myList:
        if element > target:
             l.append(element)
    return len(l)
```

So, yes, there is an intermediate list - generator expression is a better choice.

Comment: Is there a way to write it if I want it to look like mine above?

Comment: (a generator expression would look nicer and perform better)

Answer (score 2):

No, you would only change `line 4`

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    counter = 0
    for element in myList:
        if element > target:
            counter = counter + 1
    return counter
```

Note that the `if` statement requires indentation on `line 5`

Comment: No changes to line 5 at all?

Comment: line 5 only increases the counter value and has nothing to do with the comparison above it.

Comment: Line 5 is only an incremental counter. You could change it to look nicer as `counter += 1`

Comment: So you wouldn't indent it so its in the if statement?

Comment: correct, the counter should have indentation otherwise it would not run

Answer (score 2):

You change line 4 to `if element > target:`:

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    counter = 0
    for element in myList:
        if element > target:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

or, you use the more functional (but probably hard to understand for a beginner):

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    return len(x for x in myList if x < target)
```

**P.S.** I've also changed `counter = counter + 1` to the nicer looking `counter += 1`.

Comment: If you're going full Python, `return sum(x > target for x in myList)` is probably better. I do appreciate you giving an answer at the OP's current level as well as the advanced answer though.

Comment: I never seem to know exactly which of `len(x ...`, `sum(1 ...` or `sum(condition ...` is the best; also, I think it boils down to which one is the best in general, not just necessarily in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

No in this case you are changing the equivalence test to a greater than test.

You are currently testing `element == target` which will execute the (properly indented) `counter = counter+1` line on every equivalence.

To do a greater than test you'd need to change the test to `element > target`.

The code would look like:

```
def countTarget2(myList, target):
    counter = 0
    for element in myList:
        if element == target:
            counter = counter + 1 # properly indented, dont forget this!
    return counter
```